# Storing and retrieving user uploaded images in parse

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have successfully been able to store user entered information into parse, but I haven't figure out how to do store a user uploaded image that would be associated with the current user in parse, and to retrieve a user image at a later time.

To clarify this, below is the code I have used for my profile creation activity, an activity that is prompted after the user has signing using social media and responds to a series of questions like age, preferred name, and where those information are later updated in the parse database and added to the current user.

Also in the activity, the user is already able to upload a picture from their device, my issue now resolves around taking that uploaded picture and storing it on parse, and associating the image with the current user who has signing using their social media account - the social media integration is done through parse.

I have looked into the following guide, but is still greatly confused.
https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#files

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;
    protected EditText mName;
    protected EditText mAge;
    protected EditText mHeadline;
    protected Button mConfirm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);

        Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");

        mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
        mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);

        mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                String age = mAge.getText().toString();
                String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();


                age = age.trim();
                name = name.trim();
                headline = headline.trim();

                if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); 
                    currentUser.put("name", name); 
                    currentUser.put("age", age); 
                    currentUser.put("headline", headline); 
                    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });


        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        String picturePath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("picturePath", "");
        if (!picturePath.equals("")) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }

        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistance);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistanceValue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMinimumAge);
        final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMinAge);

        seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMaximumAge);
        final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMaxAge);

        seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this




        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Locate the image in res > 
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picturePath");
                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                Object image = null;
                try {
                    String path = null;
                    image = readInFile(path);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create the ParseFile
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath", (byte[]) image);
                // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                file.saveInBackground();

                // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
                ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");

                // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
                imgupload.put("Image", "picturePath");


                // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

                // Create the class and the columns
                imgupload.saveInBackground();

                // Show a simple toast message


            }
        });
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }

        }

        private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            byte[] data = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            input_stream.close();
            return buffer.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You really need to understand the nature of async code, calling `saveInBackground()` is like putting eggs on to boil, you've started a process that will finish some time later, the next thing you do has to be aware that the "eggs" aren't cooked yet, otherwise things get very messy!

Answer (score 0):

> Also in the activity, the user is already able to upload a picture
>   from their device, my issue now resolves around taking that uploaded
>   picture and storing it on parse, and associating the image with the
>   current user who has signing using their social media account - the
>   social media integration is done through parse.

Read the docs on files and on the response type when a file is upload to parse.com

```
"media":{"__type":"File","name":"e580f231-...-picf1","url":"http://files.parse.com/..52d6-picf1"}
```

So, after POST on the file to parse, you have a logical FILE entity that you can then point to  in another class.

In that other clase , you can also point to the user who created the FILE.

```
Class2  {"createdby" : pointer($user), "media" : pointer($file)}
```

With that, you have a separate class with 2 , pointer types ( toUser, toFile ) and the col headers on the data browser will show :

pointer<_User>   for the user

file             for the file